# Building E-Bike Help

Tags: motorcycle, battery, alternator

I am building an e-bike using an electric skill-saw, a car alternator, and a 20Ah battery. I have a few questions because I am new to this stuff.

- Should I have the motor in between the wheel and the alternator and
  it all be chain driven?
- Or should I have the motor directly on the wheel and have a belt
  running between the motor in the wheel to the alternator?

Also, the alternator is to make the battery life last longer, if that will work (I'm not sure). For the record, I AM NOT trying to charge the battery with this, I just want it to last longer.

- My final question is how would I get the battery to connect to the
  alternator and the skill saw at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your project sounds interesting. To be honest, this site is for maintenance & repair more than invention/design, so it is possible you may not get an answer. Good luck.

Comment: Do you know where I could go to get advice for invention/design? I only came here because there might be mechanics or DIY car experimenters that would understand motors and alternators more than me.

Comment: Sorry, I do not. Leave it here. There may be someone who has some experience who will read it. I was wanting you to know not to be discouraged if you do not get an answer. I am going to edit your title to see if it helps.

Comment: Solar battery bank to recharge the battery when your not or when you are riding lol

Comment: As mentioned in [fred_dot_u's answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/53958), it is not recommended to use an altenator, however you could use an altenator for regenerative braking, using a clutch-mechanism, so that the altenator is not connected to the wheels, except when you want to slow down, it will use the kinectic energy of the bicycle to charge up the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your question is based almost entirely on the use of an alternator, this answer should provide a global "solution."

You should have NO alternator (or generator).

An alternator will remove additional capacity from your battery, because the energy necessary to drive the alternator will be removed from the battery. That energy will not propel the bicycle forward. The alternator cannot provide to the battery more energy than it uses, becoming a net drain on the entire system.

It will not make the battery last longer, it will reduce it. Efficiency losses are accepted by the engineering community, because it's a law of physics, and designs are built around those losses.

I own a number of different electrically propelled vehicles and have been asked many times why I don't, for example, have a wheel off the back driving an alternator to charge the battery. This is mechanically similar to your question.

Ignoring for a moment the alternator aspect, having an additional wheel adds weight and rolling resistance. The energy necessary to move that wheel must come from the battery. This increases the depletion of the battery over the un-wheeled design. Loss point one.

Add an alternator and wiring, add weight. Loss point two.

Alternators have bearings and magnetic field interaction, which absorb energy. Loss point three.

The circuitry for energy management in an alternator has a conversion factor less than unity. Loss point four.

Adding up these losses means that the additional system(s) on this electric vehicle shortens the range, not increases it.

A bicycle without additional equipment and well maintained is considered the most energy efficient mode of transport. When you add weight consisting of a battery and motor, that level of efficiency is reduced, but compensated for by having the motor "take up the slack."

If you are intent to add a motor to a bicycle, consider that the motor has a specific range of rpm in which it is most efficient (miles per kilowatt hour) and a different range in which it is most powerful. Some manufacturers can provide graphs of this information, although I have found it to be rare.

Perform research regarding what is called mid-drives or crank-drive motor assist and you will find that you'll get the best result by using the motor to drive the pedals (with or without a freewheel) and use the bicycle gearing to keep the motor rpm in the desired range.

Hub motors are notoriously inefficient in that they must operate from zero rpm to maximum. This inefficiency is compensated by having large powerful batteries (or reduced range). Mid-drive systems are known for improved performance if desired as well as improved efficiency.

My e-assist bicycle used a mid-drive configuration as well as nearly perfect matching of rpm and operator preferred cadence. I had electrical consumption figures of one-fourth to one-fifth that of hub motor users.

Some trade-off is made due to the additional mechanical complexity, slightly increased noise and weight of having a mid-drive, but the increase in efficiency and range more than made up for it.

I would provide links to references for the above statements, but for the fact that it is primarily direct experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I was to get rid of the alternator (which I am) and use say a 45Ah battery, and have that directly to the saw motor, with an ESC of sorts in between the two, would that be the most efficient way of doing this? This bike is supposed to be for recreational use, not for distance. It is a little bit about eco friendly because I don't want to use gas because of it being a fossil fuel yadda yadda, but I don't plan on it being specifically for going green and distance. In all honesty, I just want a decent speed bike that I can have fun on out of household parts. and

Comment: I would want to add gears, as you said to maintain a certain rpm, and to not eat up the battery as fast. If that is what you mean't with the gears?

Comment: many bicycles today have a set of gears at the cranks, usually two or three and another set at the rear wheel, as many as ten, but more often 5 (old) to 8 (newer). Gearing on a bicycle is to match the engine rpm (human bean) to the conditions (uphill, flat, downhill, headwind, earthquake, etc). When you add a motor to the bike, in the form of a mid-drive (crank mounted motor), you want to match the gear in which you operate to provide the best conditions for the motor and the human bean.

Comment: For sure, and how would you recommend that I could put the motor on the crank? Just straight on the outside where a pedal would be? Also for an ESC, is having a plugin ESC extension practical?

Comment: One of the more sophisticated crank driven designs is called the Stokemonkey. It uses a chainring on the left side of the crank which is driven by the motor. This particular design also requires that the operator always pedal. There are modifications of this design that have a freewheel, but I'm not all that familiar with those. Some research on your end will find many resources. Consider also to visit endless sphere forum for e-bikes.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I'm gonna start this project with coincidence thanks to you! :D

Comment: It would be much more efficient to just buy a ready made ebike. You don’t want to make the bike so heavy that after the battery dies you end up pushing it to get back.